# Wordpress image sizes - scale and crop away odd number pixels after resize

Tags: wordpress, resize, image-scaling, retina

My settings for large image sizes are max-height: 1024 and max-width: 1024

Some images when scaled down to 1024 width end up having a odd numbered height (683px). Is there a way to fix this - that is scale down and if the have odd numbered height/width on the other side, crop a pixel off.

Comment: I'm curious, why exactly is that a problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing blurry images and according to some sources the reason is because of odd number pixels.

[link](http://www.kwiksher.com/forums/index.php?topic=629.15)

Comment: I'd love to see a fiddle of that. I mean - yes, blurry images are a sign of browser resize, but I have no idea how odd or even number of pixels in height can cause stuff.